# Kotlin Android: After updating Kotlin to 1.2.51, build fails. Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin

After updating Kotlin to 1.2.51 I cannot build my app. I have invalidated caches numerous times, and feel like I have tried everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've posted logs and some code below so hopefully you can better understand the problem - any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Logs**

```
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/checkers/DeclarationCheckerContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.CacheKt.getSetterInfos(Cache.kt:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.CacheKt.traverseClass(Cache.kt:59)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.CacheKt.access$traverseClass(Cache.kt:1)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.ClassTraversalCache.getClassInfo(Cache.kt:29)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.CacheKt.getInfo(Cache.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.InstanceComponentDescriptor.getRegistrations(Components.kt:24)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.ComponentRegistry.buildRegistrationMap(Registry.kt:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.ComponentRegistry.addAll(Registry.kt:36)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.ComponentStorage.composeDescriptors(Storage.kt:124)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.ComponentStorage.compose(Storage.kt:118)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.StorageComponentContainer.compose(Container.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.container.DslKt.composeContainer(Dsl.kt:24)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TargetPlatformKt.createContainer(TargetPlatform.kt:149)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend.java.di.InjectionKt.createContainerForLazyResolveWithJava(injection.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend.java.di.InjectionKt.createContainerForTopDownAnalyzerForJvm(injection.kt:141)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend.java.di.InjectionKt.createContainerForTopDownAnalyzerForJvm$default(injection.kt:140)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.createContainer(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:175)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:86)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:162)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:109)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:451)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:218)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:518)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:400)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:895)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:925)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:894)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:399)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.checkers.DeclarationCheckerContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginURLClassLoader$SelfThenParentURLClassLoader.findClass(PluginURLClassLoader.kt:50)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 66 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
```

**App: build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.dagger_version = '2.11'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fil.uk.mobile.eventual"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.4.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':gd')

    compile 'me.rishabhkhanna:CustomToggle:1.0.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.ramotion.expandingcollection:expanding-collection:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.3'
//dependencies
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"

    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'

    compile 'de.siegmar:fastcsv:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'

    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'

    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
    //Word utils
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

}
```

I am also getting unresolved references to some libraries:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OMsA.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck with this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing Android Studio, and then remove your project from the list of recent projects. 
Click on "Open Existing project". This should fix the problem. 
This worked for me when I was stuck with "please select Android SDK error after the update. 
Tried Clean project, Invalidate many times But this solution worked.